Camera Not available in raspi-config
I use a Pi Zero 2w Rev. 1.0. I have installed bookworm 32bit and it is up to date. With vcgencmd get_camera i get supported=0 detected=0 .libcamera interfaces=0. So i have checked the raspi-config. In the Interface options is the camera Not available. What is wrong that i can't enable the camera? Can anybody Help me. Thanks. Lars

Have you bothered to read the Bookworm documentation?

Set this camera_auto_detect=0 in /boot/firmware/config.txt
which should be like this by default in config file
camera_auto_detect=1

I hadn't really read through them until now. I looked through the picamera2 manual again and connected the cable between the Raspberry and the camera. And lo and behold, it works.

are you saying that the camera was not plugged in?
